# Serialization approach in relationship

Tags: codefluent

We are using codefluent entities for the BOM, webapi for the controllers and angularjs Framework on the client side.

We are facing a problem when storing reference of an object in the parent object. Anytime, reference would be nulled by generated code.

Given two entities with a Relationship EntA[EntAId, prop1, EntB] and EntB[EntBId, prop1, prop2] 
I end up with two classes:

```
class EntA{
   EntAId
   prop1
   EntB
   EntBEntBId
}
```

and

```
class EntB{
   EntBId
   prop1
   prop2
}
```

CodeFluent has generated following code:

```
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(IsNullable=false)]
    [System.ComponentModel.DataObjectFieldAttribute(true)]
    public System.Guid EntBEntBId
    {
        get
        {
            if (((this._EntBEntBId.Equals(CodeFluentPersistence.DefaultGuidValue) == true) 
                        && (this._entB != null)))
            {
                this._EntBEntBId = this._entB.EntBId;
            }
            return this._EntBEntBId;
        }
        set
        {
            if ((System.Collections.Generic.EqualityComparer<System.Guid>.Default.Equals(value, this.EntBEntBId) == true))
            {
                return;
            }
            this._entB = null;
            this._EntBEntBId = value;
            this.EntityState = CodeFluent.Runtime.CodeFluentEntityState.Modified;
            this.OnPropertyChanged(new System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs("EntB"));
            this.OnPropertyChanged(new System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs("EntBEntBId"));
        }
    }

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIgnoreAttribute()]
    public Namespace.EntB.EntB EntB
    {
        get
        {
            if ((this._entB == null))
            {
                this._entB = Namespace.EntB.EntB.Load(this._EntBEntBId);
            }
            return this._entB;
        }
        set
        {
            this._EntBEntBId = CodeFluentPersistence.DefaultGuidValue;
            this._entB = value;
            this.EntityState = CodeFluent.Runtime.CodeFluentEntityState.Modified;
            this.OnPropertyChanged(new System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs("EntB"));
            this.OnPropertyChanged(new System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs("EntBEntBId"));
        }
    }
```

On client side (using Angular) I want to register `objectA.EntBEntBId` without sending the whole EntB object. Thus I would consider this snippet below to nullify EntB.

```
if(objectA.EntB)
    objectA.EntB = null
```

This end up sending correct Stream to server (without the whole B object being serialized).

When HTTP PUT call is triggered, webapi would valuate classes first going through get/set methods. Property EntBEntBId would be valuated correctly, but then setter of EntB property would keep erasing previous value (as EntB is currently null).

Is there any way to avoid such behavior ?

Thanks in advance for your answer;

Answer (score 1):

I might be answering my own question, but when using `delete objectA.entB` instead of `objectA.entB = null` Stream would not contain entB property, thus not going through setter of it.

Comment: Seems a good solution. Maybe you can clone the JavaScript object before deleting its property. As you are using angularjs, you can do that using an [HttpInterceptor](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http)